# Gladman AES library - safe to ignore compiler warnings?

Tags: encryption, assembly, warnings, aes, inline-assembly

Compiling the current `gladman AES library`, I'm getting warnings in `aes_modes.c`, all saying `"warning C4731: ... frame pointer register 'ebx' modified by inline assembly code"`

This sounds pretty worrying, I don't want my app to crash with a stack corruption, but I can barely read x86 assembler.  Can anyone advise if these warnings can be safely ignored?

Answer (score 0):

This is safe to ignore if its saved and restored. For eg.

```
push ebx
;use the ebx to do something else
pop ebx
```

See this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywz8xf2a.aspx), which explains what that error means.

If its not done in the code, you can add that and test it.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is not done in the code, but it can't be fixed as easily as you recommend because the code seems to be using ebx as a way to return results from assembler into C.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is NOT safe to ignore this warning.
The code had been working fine on XP, but when tested on Windows 7 it crashes within the aes_decrypt assembler routine.  I am going to move over to a pure C version.